# How to predict the time of next trajectory for users

Tags: machine-learning, geostatistics

I am working with the Geolife dataset and would like to create a statistical model to predict when users will go on their next trip. The implication is to see if we can build a model to be able to better predict a good time to send a reminder to someone about to drive.

The data I have is approximately 10000 trajectories from ~ 70 users. The data that I have includes the start time, end time, mode of transportation, and the location they started and stopped. I also have all the points in between the start and endpoints of the trajectories.

I would imagine that some kind of Markov Chain model would work the best but I am unsure how I would create the model to produce a continuous output.

Comment: I would suggest survival modeling for this such as Cox Proportional Hazards regression.  You could then send a reminder when their hazard score crosses some threshold.

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks, @Barker.